# I have a lot of 404 error page what should I do?

Tags: hyperlink, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

i changed the CMS i use for my website so all links are new . i don’t want any of old URLs in google index , the problem is this old links are pointed from another sites

Answer (score 0):

- Send message to external site owners and ask to change the links;
- Open Google Search Console and go to "Google Index / Remove URLs"; you can temporarily block old URLs (https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598466?visit_id=1-636513744496718362-859155776&rd=1);
- Anyway removed old URL will automatically disapear from Google Index but it takes a long time (months or even year).